# EF Core InMemory not throwing: Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We have a model that's similar to one in https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11888.

Like in the issue above, when doing it with SqlServer we get an exception

`Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'Person [Added] <- Owner { 'OwnerId' } Car [Added] <- ActiveCar { 'ActiveCarId' } Person [Added]'.`

However, when we unit-test with InMemory database this exception is not thrown.
Is there a way to get this exception with In Memory database as well?

Comment: Try with SQLite for testing with ef core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite

Comment: The documentation is very explicit that the EF InMemory is _not_ a relational Db. It has other deviations, like always Including all nav properties.

Comment: InMemory version of SQLite is a nice option, thanks!

Comment: @bommelding, I know it's not a relational DB, but maybe there's a known workaround. E.g., I could imagine overriding SaveChanges and manually checking for some things. However, `always Including all nav properties` - that's simply not true.

Comment: I was quite sure about the nav properties - I will have to look it up. But the workaround was already mentioned: SqlLite. Will be closer to ms-sql then anything you can do with InMemory.

Comment: I have a project where I use both, SqlLite for testing the mappings and configurations, InMemory in a mock for the application services.